# Can there exist Tables with no Non-Prime Attributes? If so, are they always normalised to 3NF?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

#### Can there exist a table with no non-prime attributes?

Here is an example of a table which I believe has no non-prime attributes:

[image]

I came to this conclusion because the list of attributes in the relation is `[id, tag_desc_id, name]` and the list of candidate keys is `[{id}, {tag_desc_id, name}]`. There are no attributes in the list of attributes that are in none of the candidate keys. Thus, there are no non-prime attributes.

Is my reasoning correct?

#### If so, is it normalised to 3NF?

The criteria for 3NF is:

> - 2NF
> - Every non-prime attribute of R is non-transitively dependent on every key of R

There are no non-prime attributes, thus 3NF is satisfied

The criteria for 2NF is:

> - 1NF
> - Every non-prime attribute is (...)

Again, there are no non-prime attributes.

#### Is this true generally?

For any table, assuming the table has a primary key `id` as above (and so 1NF is satisfied), and the table has no non-prime attributes, is it always the case that the table is normalised to the third normal form (3NF)?

Comment: All the three questions have an answer yes.